# How do you enable Core Spotlight to index app content in React Native

Tags: react-native, corespotlight

What's the easiest way to go about indexing a React Native app so that content within the app appears in Spotlight searches?

Answer (score 2):

If you're still interested in indexing your app content using React Native, I've [written a plugin to do just that](https://github.com/jdmunro/react-native-spotlight-search).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: You're welcome :) please log any feature requests or issues you find!

Answer (score 1):

As you've figured out, there's no built-in react-native support for this. The only option for you to utilize the `Core Spotlight` framework capabilities is to create your own [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) which will expose this functionality to your react-native code. You can also try to find someone who already wrote this module and made it open source, but I guess you've already tried that.

Since this is the only way, it is also the easiest... That said, it should be pretty easy to implement it yourself, assuming you have some experience with iOS development. If you run into problems you can post your code and I can point you in the right direction if necessary.